# swift - how to access public constants without having to instanciate class, as in C#

Tags: swift

Should not be needed create an instance of a class to access a public constant. I recently started working in Swift, so I must be missing something here.

In this simple example:

```
public class MyConstants{
    public let constX=1;
}
public class Consumer{
     func foo(){
          var x = MyConstants.constX;// Compiler error: MyConstants don't have constX
     }
}
```

This foo code gives an compile error. To work, I need to create an instance of the MyConstants like this:

```
public class Consumer{
     func foo(){
       var dummy = MyConstants();
       var x = dummy.constX;
    }
}
```

Adding static to constX is not allowed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `struct` with `static` types.`struct`are more appropriate as in `enum` you can only bind one type of associative values but you can contain the "Type Property of any type" in both.

```
public struct MyConstants{
    static let constX=1;
}
public class Consumer{
    func foo(){
        var x = MyConstants.constX;
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree that a struct is more appropriate than an enum, but it's possible to create static immutable variables of different data types in enums

Comment: with `enum`. we can use only one type of associate values so you can not bind `string` and `Int`values with `enums` altogether.

Comment: In his self answer, the OP is using the enum as a container for static variables - try this: `enum Constants { static let myConstant = 5; static let myData = "hello" }`

Comment: @Antonio thanks, i know that we can include "Type Property" with `enums`.

Answer (score 7):

You should use immutable static variables. Unfortunately classes support computed properties only with the `class` modifier - the compiler outputs an error stating that *class variables are not **yet** supported*.

But in structs it's possible to create static data members:

```
struct Constants {
    static let myConstant = 5
}
```

and of course it's not required to create an instance, as the immutable static property can simply be accessed as:

```
Constants.myConstant
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a constant, you can also "fake" the as-yet-unsupported class variable with a class computed property, which does currently work:

```
public class MyConstants{
    public class var constX: Int { return 1 };
}
public class Consumer{
    func foo(){
        var x = MyConstants.constX; // Now works fine.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For string constants what I do is put the bunch of constants into responsible class file in the following way:

```
public enum NotificationMessage: String {

    case kTimerNotificationId = "NotificationIdentifier"
}
```

Then for use it from any other point of the code just:

```
println("\(NotificationMessage.kTimerNotificationId.rawValue)")
```

Do not forget .rawValue.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution below, but hope someone can clarify or post a better solution

```
enum MyConstantsV2 {
    static var constX = 1
}

public class Consumerv2{

    func foo(){
       var x = MyConstantsV2.constX;
    }
}
```